# Java applet application on Internet Explore not loading

Tags: java, applet, rpa, workfusion

I am using java applet application on Internet Explore, the version of java for the applet application is jre-6u26,

After installing Workfusion RPA Express on my PC the Internet Explore applet application stopped loading.

Please help me on this.

Comment: *"Please help me on this"* - Applets are dead, sorry, but they are. Most browsers either actively disable them or don't support the, now deprecated, plugin

Comment: (most) browsers no longer support applets. why would you still want to use them?

Comment: We are running an automobile industry the applet software provided by MARUTI SUZUKI car manufacturer and its a global software, is there any way to use both RPA worfusion and the applet on Internet Explore together.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, could JavaFx be an alternative here?

Comment: No our applet software work only with jre6u26 version of Java

Comment: @Arvind No ... for the same reasons that the applet plugin has been deprecated

Comment: @YADHURAJMAGESHKUMAR you can use applets as much as you want, but browsers don't support/allow them any longer. they simply won't work.

Comment: I have no issues with our applet software, it’s working charm if Workfusion not installed, my concern only is I wants to use both together.

Comment: @YADHURAJMAGESHKUMAR try updating to a somewhat up to date browser and say that again ..

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for your positive replay, sure ill accomplish this and post the result ASAP.

Comment: the point is, applets don't work in the latest browsers anymore, the technology is no longer supported.

Comment: You can use applets in Internet Explorer. Workfusion RPA Express  may updated the client JRE and your applets very probably does not support that version, there maybe other settings (e.g. security that must be apply) that prevents your appets to run. Turn on applet tracing and java console in control panel / configure java and check the output. The reason will be there

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the Java add-on in IE browser